# Add disconnected vertices to a graph in an optimal way

Tags: r, optimization, graph-theory

I have a real-world problem, for which I believe the solution lies in graph theory. Unfortunately, I have no experience with this field of mathematics, hence I would need some help with this exercise.

There are n=1000 towns, where 600 have internet connection and the 300 remaining do not. The disconnected towns are in 2 clusters on the map:

```
set.seed(123)
n_vill <- 1000
connected <- 700
disconnected <- n_vill-connected


df_connected <- data.frame(id = 1:connected,
                 x = runif(connected,17,20),
                 y = runif(connected,46,49),
                 has_int = 1,
                 pop = round(rexp(connected,0.002)))


df_disconnected <- data.frame(id = 701:n_vill,
                              x = c(runif(disconnected/2,17,18),runif(disconnected/2,19,20)),
                              y = c(runif(disconnected/2,46,47),runif(disconnected/2,48,49)),
                              has_int = 0,
                              pop = round(rexp(disconnected,0.005)))

df <- rbind(df_connected,df_disconnected)
```

My task is to connect the disconnected towns to those towns connected in an optimal way - there are costs to connect each village (the distance between them) and benefits (the population that lives in the town gets internet). Let's say, the budget for the distance is constrained. Hence, I would try to connect the biggest and closest towns first and leave the small and remote ones until the end. However, if there is a small town "on the way" from big disconnected town to connected town, I should include it as well (I add some population at limited costs).

The only solution I came up with is the Minimum Spanning Tree, which connects all points minimizing the distance. However, this approach has the issue that it connects *all* towns and does not consider their population, constrained budget or prioritization of connections. Is there a better and simple way to do this? Ideally in `R`.

Here is the code I used:

```
library(igraph)
require(leaflet)
require(geosphere)
require(tidyverse)
require(sp)
rm(list = ls())


mat2list <- function(D) {
    n = dim(D)[1]
    k <- 1
    e <- matrix(ncol = 3,nrow = n*(n-1)/2)
    for (i in 1:(n-1)) {
        for (j in (i+1):n) {
            e[k,] = c(rownames(D)[i],colnames(D)[j],as.numeric(D[i,j]))
            k<-k+1
        }
    }
    return(as.data.frame(e))
}
get_coords <- function(x){
    xy1 <- as.numeric(df[df$id==x[1],2:3])
    xy2 <- as.numeric(df[df$id==x[2],2:3])
    
    has_int1 <- as.numeric(as.character(df$has_int[df$id==x[1]]))
    has_int2 <- as.numeric(as.character(df$has_int[df$id==x[2]]))
    
    col_ciara <-  ifelse(sum(has_int1,has_int2)<2,'red','green')
    
    return(list(coords = c(xy1[1],xy2[1],xy1[2],xy2[2]), color = col_ciara))
} 

dist_mat <-  distm(x = df[,c('x','y')], y = df[,c('x','y')], fun=distHaversine) 
rownames(dist_mat)<- df$id
colnames(dist_mat) <- df$id

ed <- mat2list(dist_mat/1000)
ed$V3 <- as.numeric(ed$V3)

beatCol <- colorFactor(palette = c('red','green'), df$has_int)

df2 <- df
coordinates(df2) <- ~x+y

map1 <- leaflet(df2)%>% 
    addCircleMarkers(label=df2$id,color = ~beatCol(has_int),radius =~log(pop, base=2),fillColor = ~beatCol(has_int),
                     fillOpacity = 0.5,opacity = 1) %>% 
    addTiles()

net <- graph.data.frame(ed[,1:2],directed = FALSE)
E(net)$weight <- as.numeric(ed[,3])
mst <- minimum.spanning.tree(net)
me <- get.edges(mst, 1:ecount(mst))

for(i in 1:nrow(me)){
    map1 <- addPolylines(map1, lat = as.numeric(get_coords(me[i,])$coords[3:4]), 
                         lng = as.numeric(get_coords(me[i,])$coords[1:2]),
                         color = get_coords(me[i,])$color)
}
map1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first step is to define the function that you want to optimize.  This will be a function of cost and benefit i.e. how much cost are you willing to incur to gain one more connected customer.  Ideally the function should be linear

maximize: o = x * cost + y * customer

when you can use linear programming to find your optimal setup.